# ¿Cómo representar una secuencia de escape obtenida manualmente?

Tags: c#

Dada la siguiente cadena en un archivo de texto "x":

```
"hola, cómo estan?\nEspero que bien! \u00FF"
```

En C# esto es representado de la siguiente forma:

```
"hola, cómo estan?\\nEspero que bien! \\u00FF"
```

Mi duda es la siguiente, ¿Cómo puedo obtener el caracter representado por la secuencia de escape `\\u00FF` por código? He logrado capturar la secuencia y mostrarla en pantalla, los escapes como `\t` o `\n` los he manejado a la perfección, pero mi problema está con las secuencias UNICODE.

---

Este es el código de la función que trabaja los escapes:

```
public static char[] input;
public static int charPos;

public static string GetEscape()
{
    string theEscape = "";
    switch (input[charPos + 1])
    {
        case '\\': theEscape += '\\'; charPos += 2; break;
        case 't': theEscape += '\t'; charPos += 2; break;
        case 'r': theEscape += '\r'; charPos += 2; break;
        case 'n': theEscape += '\n'; charPos += 2; break;
        // Tenemos que obtener los siguientes 4 caracteres 
        // para reconocer el caracter UNICODE.
        case 'u': case 'U':
        {
            // Obtenemos la secuencia de escape.
            try {
                theEscape += ("\\" + input[charPos + 1].ToString()
                                   + input[charPos + 2] 
                                   + input[charPos + 3] 
                                   + input[charPos + 4] 
                                   + input[charPos + 5]); 
            } catch {
                throw new Exception("Caracter inesperado"); }
            charPos += 6;
        } break;
        default: 
            Console.WriteLine("Secuencia de escape no soportada"); 
            return null;
    }
    return theEscape;
}
```

Función para capturar toda la cadena:

```
public static string ScanString()
{
    string theStr = "";
    ++charPos; // Comemos la primera comila '"'
    while (charPos < input.Length && input[charPos] != '"')
    {
        // Si es un escape, pasarlo.
        if (input[charPos] == '\\')
        {   theStr += GetEscape();
            continue; }
        // De lo contrario, solo tomar el caracter.
        theStr += input[charPos];
        ++charPos;
    }
    //if (IsEOF && input[charPos - 1] != '"') throw new Exception("Unterminated string.");
    //else
    ++charPos; // Comemos la ultima comilla '"'
    return theStr;
}
```

Hasta ahora, si utilizo un `string` como: `\u00FF` (`\\u00FF`) el código reconoce la secuencia de escape, pero necesito que el valor `00FF` se traduzca a su respectivo caracter UNICODE (`00FF es igual a 'ÿ'`)

Por lo que la salida con el `string` que he puesto al inicio debería dar como resultado:

```
"hola, cómo estan?
 Espero que bien! ÿ"
```

En la consola, Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si ya tienes localizado y guardado el valor ya casi lo tienes. Suponiendo que tienes el valor `00FF` en la variable `codePoint`, simplemente:

```
int code = int.Parse(codePoint, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
string unicodeString = char.ConvertFromUtf32(code);
```

Ahora ya tienes tu valor en `unicodeString`.

Más información [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994459/getting-unicode-string-from-its-code-c-sharp) (pregunta con respuesta del SO original).

Answer (score 0):

Este código toma la cadena del número hexadecimal "00FF" y lo convierte en su correspondiente caracter unicode. En C# Char es Unicode de 16 bits, por lo que en ese rango puedes usar una variable Char para guardar el caracter.

> int uniDec = int.Parse("00FF",System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
>
> char codChar = Convert.ToChar(uniDec);